# How to center a control on the primary screen?

Tags: c#, winforms

This should center `menuLabel` on the X axis. But when I run it, `menuLabel` is too far to the right.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
menuLabel.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left +
                     (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2) - (menuLabel.Width / 2);
```

Comment: Your form is not the same as the primary screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your `menuLabel` is located on some `Form` or some other container control, so its coordinates are relative to that parent control or `Form`.
To convert screen coordinates to the local ones use the [`Control.PointToClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
Example for a `Form` as a container (assuming this code is in the `Form`'s class):

```
menuLabel.Left = PointToClient(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left +
                 (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - menuLabel.Width) / 2);
```

Example for a `someControl` as a container:

```
menuLabel.Left = someControl.PointToClient(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left +
                 (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - menuLabel.Width) / 2);
```